# std::errc ABI portability

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

I've built [this project](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/49c54870c1f99bbdbce0b20ee723a82c8bb8ea6d/lib/Serialization/SerializedModuleLoader.cpp#L363) from source.  I have a setup that hits this codepath:

```
if (err != std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory) {
    Ctx.Diags.diagnose(moduleID.second, diag::sema_opening_import,
                       moduleID.first, err.message());
  }
```

On my system (Debian Jessie), this condition evaluates to false.  Therefore we do not call `Ctx.Diags.diagnose`.

However, I took the binary I built and gave it to a friend who runs Ubuntu.  Under the exact same conditions on his system, the if statement evaluates to true, and `err.message()` is `No such file or directory`.

How is that possible?  I thought `std::errc` is supposed to be portable?  `ENOENT` is `2` on both systems, as required by POSIX.

I assume this has something to do with libstd on his system at runtime being different than it is on my system at buildtime, but I don't understand why, or how to build a portable version.

Comment: What are the relevant GCC versions?

Comment: There's a lot going on behind the scenes with that `!=` comparison - eventually involving comparing two `error_category`s for identity. GCC 5 has an ABI change on `error_category`-related things (because of the `std::string` change), so they actually have two `generic_category()`s and two `system_category()`s (the newer version is in an inline namespace). If your code somehow managed to mix the two, that could explain the behavior.

Comment: No GCC installed.  The project was actually built with clang-3.5-10 (Jessie) and the Ubuntu machine has clang-3.6.2-1.  I do have a *lib*gcc, libgcc-4.9.2-10, and the Ubuntu system has libgcc-5.2.1-22ubuntu2.

Comment: Well, you claim to be using libstdc++, so there must be a GCC somewhere...

Comment: libstdc++ is a different package than GCC?  The program is linked with libstdc++, but complied with clang.

Comment: /sigh. It's part of GCC but I suppose packaged separately. I stand by my "mismatched error category" hypothesis, anyway, since that's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

@T.C.'s hypothesis in the comments above is correct.

The ABI for C++11 features changed between the experimental C++0x support in GCC 4.9 and the finished C++11 support in GCC 5.x, so if your code uses C++11 you can't compile with GCC 4.9 and then use the libstdc++ from GCC 5.

This is [PR 66438](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66438). I closed that as invalid, because mixing 4.9 and 5.x doesn't work for C++11 code.